# Make macOS ignore the creation or modification of .DS_Store file when showing last modified time

Tags: finder, macos

Apple has brought the system integrity protection to a new level by introducing the read-only system volume in Catalina. This makes altering the system process even more difficulty. And I think in the future it would be more and more difficult to prevent the creation of finder trash like `.DS_Store` file with tools like [asepsis](https://github.com/binaryage/asepsis). So I think I'll just give up on fighting with the creation of those files.

So my next wish is, **is there any way that we could make the last-modified time of the folder untouched when a new `.DS_Store` is created?** It is extremely annoying to have the time stamps modified just because you went through some folders in finder.

Comment: Did asepsis actually stop working (with SIP off) or are you just worried it will in the future?

Comment: @Wowfunhappy yep, it did stop. And actually it did took me awhile before I could figure out how to fully uninstall the asepsis and stop it from keep crashing finder. (You actually need to go to the recovery mode to change the `DesktopServicesPriv.framework` back to the system version.)

Comment: I wonder if enough people could make a case to extend the SMB setting to other uses. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208209 I can't see Apple changing the modification date since the folder is modified when a write happens, but suppressing the write seems reasonable to argue if the use case was convincing enough.

Comment: @bmike I feel like if Apple was going to do it, they would have ages ago. This complaint is as old as DS_Store files...

Comment: Since asepsis has an actively maintained fork, I wouldn't give up hope just yet. Might just take the author some time... https://github.com/fnesveda/asepsis

Comment: @Wowfunhappy actually this one https://github.com/JK3Y/asepsis has more recent activities and was the one that I used. I am just so frustrated that apple choose to ignore users complaints on the DS_Store. It should be such a subtle modification for them. Feel like being raped by apple so badly for no reason. Why on earth would apple ever choose to stick to those files.